# Junit difference between assertEquals(Double, Double) and assertEquals(double, double, delta)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I had a junit test asserting two Double objects with the following:

```
Assert.assertEquals(Double expected, Double result);
```

This was was fine then I decided to change it to use the primitive double instead which turned out to be deprecated unless you also provide a delta.

so what I am wondering is what is the difference between using the Double object or the primitive type in this assertEquals? Why is using the objects without a delta ok but then using the primitives without a delta is deprecated? Is Java doing something in the background which already has a default delta value taken into account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is NO [assert method in JUnit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) with the signature

```
assertEquals(Double expected, Double result);
```

There is one, however, generic for objects:

```
assertEquals(Object expected, Object result);
```

This calls the objects' `equals` method and as you can expect, it is not recommended to use this for comparing `Double` objects.

For doubles, as you observed, it is absolutely necessary to use a delta for comparison, to avoid issues with floating-point rounding (explained already in some other answers). If you use the 3-argument version of `assertEquals` with `double` arguments

```
assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta);
```

your `Double`s will get silently unboxed to `double` and everything will work fine (and your tests won't fail unexpectedly :-).

Comment: +1 re unboxing, yes, with the caveat that you'll have slightly different behaviour if one or other Double is null. With the Object, you'll get a nice message, with the delta, you'll get a NullPointerException.

Comment: My experience is that these methods don't work well for very large numbers under some circumstances, particularly if your data varies over orders of magnitude. Two numbers may have a very small percent error, but require a seemingly large delta to match. But that same delta wouldn't work for much smaller values in your data. In some cases, even very large numbers can be expected to match over nearly all significant digits. In other cases, such as when comparing two optimized FFT algorithms, that's much less likely. A more robust method is to constrain the relative error.

Comment: @orodbhen To make it work one should calculate delta basing on exponent of the expected value, so if `double e` is the expected value, then delta should be `double d = Math.pow(10, Math.log10(Math.abs(e)) - 12);` where `12` is maximal practical number of significant digits. If you multiply the log10 by value < 1.0, then test will fail for `e` having large positive exponent and, on the contrary, if you multiply log10 by value > 1.0, it will fail for `e` having large negative exponent — and this is the effect you were writing about. So make sure delta is well fit to exponent of expected value.

Comment: "your Doubles will get silently unboxed to double and everything will work fine "; So... What will happen if my expected and result are both `null` when using the second signature?

Answer (score 7):

Double math rarely if ever gives *exactly* equal results.  For example, `0.1 * 0.1 != 0.01`.  You usually need at least some delta in comparing double-precision results.

On the other hand, if you're comparing boxed `Double`s, it assumes you want the exact equality.  Java doesn't have a default delta value taken into account, but `Double.equals` has slightly different behavior from `==`: in particular, [its handling of NaNs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

This makes sense in testing, because `Double.NaN != Double.NaN`, but in a test, if you expected an `NaN` and `NaN` was returned, that's a correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

Better write something like this:

```
assertEquals(23.0, 250.0, 0.0)
```

0.0 - it is delta. Read why yours methods are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

[SOURCE.](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double,%20double%29)
Asserts that two doubles or floats are equal to within a positive delta. If they are not, an AssertionError is thrown. If the expected value is infinity then the delta value is ignored.NaNs are considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that comparing doubles, primitive or object, is useless without a delta.  Knowing how flowing point numbers work is key to doing numerical work.

The object might be using .equals under the covers; the primitive has no option besides ==.

Just because the object version isn't using a delta doesn't make that a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to update regarding JUnit 5. Regardless of the version, `assertEquals(Double expected, Double actual)` gets routed to `assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual)`, because, as others already explained, `Double` is a primitive wrapper that implicitly extends `Object`.

But `assertEquals(double expected, double actual)` (with two primitives rather than two primitive wrappers) in a JUnit 4 context calls a deprecated procedure. I don't know if it was already deprecated in JUnit 3. But guess what: it's not deprecated in JUnit 5.

Floating point types like `double` are inherently imprecise. Suppose `expected = 0.3`. How is `actual` computed? If it's `3.0 / 10` the result might be exact. But if it's the infamous `0.1 + 0.2`, it will be off by 0.00000000000000004 (which somehow becomes 5.551115123125783 × 10<sup>−17</sup> if you subtract 0.3).

Generally speaking, floating point multiplication and division are more reliable than floating point addition and subtraction.

The following example comes from a test class with an `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*` static import.

```
    @Test
    void testDeltaExample() {
        double expected = 0.3;
        double actual = 0.1 + 0.2;
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

Result:

> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <0.3> but was:
> <0.30000000000000004>     at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)     at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:70)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:65)
> at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:868)
> ...

Do you care if it's off by a tiny amount like that? If you don't, then you'll want a delta like 0.0000000000000001.

You can still use "vintage" JUnit from JUnit 5, if you want (but you shouldn't want to for any reason other than that you're migrating existing test suites, or to see that it can be done).

```
    @Test
    void testDeltaExample() {
        double expected = 0.3;
        double actual = 0.1 + 0.2;
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

(your IDE should show a strike-through in the line before the closing brace). This test will fail even if `expected` and `actual` have the exact same bit pattern (which they won't in this example).

> java.lang.AssertionError: Use assertEquals(expected, actual, delta) to
> compare floating-point numbers    at
> org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)     at
> org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:667)    at
> org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:656)
> ...

Many quite intelligent Java programmers who have learned such complicated things as SQL joins simply didn't care to learn about floating point numbers, so they just used a delta of 0.0.

And so it seems that the JUnit developers decided it wasn't their job to educate people on the foibles of floating point. So `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(double expected, double actual)` is technically new and not at all deprecated.

To be absolutely clear, floating point comparison with a delta is still available in JUnit 5. From a Scala perspective, you can regard it as `assertEquals(expected: Double, actual: Double, delta: Double = 0.0)`.