# Default Delta Value

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, delta, junit5

In JUnit testing, I was curious what the default value of the delta would be if you did not supply one. Im referring to this method in particular.

```
    assertEquals(java.lang.String message, double expected, double actual, double delta)
```

If you didnt supply  delta would it just be 0? I wasnt able to find any information regarding to it in the API. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you not supply one? Just curious to understand your thoughts over it.

Comment: @nullpointer The "assertEquals" method is overloaded so there is an option to not supply one.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242224/junit-difference-between-assertequalsdouble-double-and-assertequalsdouble-d

Comment: @brendan612 true but this signature is deprecated and from one of the previous versions it starts to fail! https://www.dropbox.com/s/g13jr60brak7w2m/fail_msg.png

Comment: *"Use assertEquals(expected, actual, delta) to compare floating-point numbers"* from the deprecated overloaded method.

Comment: Whoops, I didnt realize they were deprecated. Thank you for the help!

Comment: This is a good case to use jshell from Java 9 to test this out and see the behavior.